# How to Edit using a ViewModel in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, mvvm

I am new to MVC and trying to understand ViewModels. I understand how to use Create and a ViewModel, But am unsure how to Edit using a View Model?

My VM:

```
public class BookingViewModel
{
    [Display (Name = "Select Patient")]
    public Guid PatientId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PatientList { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select Practice")]
    public Guid PracticeId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PracticeList { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select Optician")]
    public Guid OpticianId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> OpticiansList { get; set; }

    public Optician Optician { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select Time")]
    public Guid TimeId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TimeList { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    // Creates a new booking
    BookingViewModel bookingViewModel = new BookingViewModel();
    // Initilises Select List
    ConfigureCreateViewModel(bookingViewModel);

    return View(bookingViewModel);

}

// Initilises Select List 
public void ConfigureCreateViewModel(BookingViewModel bookingViewModel)
{
    // Displays Opticians Name - Needs changed to full name
    bookingViewModel.OpticiansList = db.Opticians.Select(o => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = o.OpticianId.ToString(),
        Text = o.User.FirstName
    });

    // Displays Patients name - needs changed to full name DOB
    bookingViewModel.PatientList = db.Patients.Select(p => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = p.PatientId.ToString(),
        Text = p.User.FirstName
    });

    // Displays Practice Name
    bookingViewModel.PracticeList = db.Practices.Select(p => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = p.PracticeId.ToString(),
        Text = p.PracticeName
    });

    // Displays Appointment Times 
    bookingViewModel.TimeList = db.Times.Select(t => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = t.TimeId.ToString(),
        Text = t.AppointmentTime
    });


}


// Allows Admin to create booking for patient 
// POST: Bookings1/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(BookingViewModel bookingViewModel)
{
    // to ensure date is in the future
    if (ModelState.IsValidField("Date") && DateTime.Now > bookingViewModel.Date)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "Please enter a date in the future");
    }



    // if model state is not valid
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Initilises Select lists
        ConfigureCreateViewModel(bookingViewModel);
        return View(bookingViewModel); // returns user to booking page
    }
    else // if model state is Valid
    {
        Booking booking = new Booking();
        // Sets isAvail to false
        booking.isAvail = false;
        booking.PracticeId = bookingViewModel.PracticeId;
        booking.Optician = bookingViewModel.Optician;
        booking.PatientId = bookingViewModel.PatientId;
        booking.Date = bookingViewModel.Date;
        booking.TimeId = bookingViewModel.TimeId;

        // Generates a new booking Id
        booking.BookingId = Guid.NewGuid();
        // Adds booking to database
        db.Bookings.Add(booking);
        // Saves changes to Database
        db.SaveChanges();
        // Redirects User to Booking Index
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

I am really unsure how to Edit a View Model, any advice would be greatly appreciated

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Booking booking = db.Bookings.Find(id);
    if (booking == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    BookingViewModel bookingViewModel = new BookingViewModel()
    {
        Date = booking.Date,
        OpticianId = booking.OpticianId,
        PatientId = booking.PatientId,
        PracticeId = booking.PracticeId,
        TimeId = booking.TimeId
    };

    return View(booking, bookingViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Booking booking)
{


    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        db.Entry(booking).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(booking);
}
```

Comment: What results are you getting from what you are currently doing?

Comment: @tcrite There is an invalid arguement error a the GET Edit Return View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no overload of [Controller.View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx) method that accepts 2 models/objects.

You `Edit()` GET method needs to be

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid? id)
{
  ....
  BookingViewModel bookingViewModel = new BookingViewModel()
  {
    ....
  }
  // Call the ConfigureCreateViewModel() method so that you SelectList's are populated 
  // as you have done in the Create() method (ConfigureViewModel might be a better name?)
  ConfigureCreateViewModel(bookingViewModel);
  return View(bookingViewModel); // adjust this
}
```

and the POST method needs to be

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(BookingViewModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureCreateViewModel(model)
    return View(model);
  }
  // Get your data model and update its properties based on the view model
  Booking booking = db.Bookings.Find(id);
  booking.PracticeId = bookingViewModel.PracticeId;
  booking.OpticianId = bookingViewModel.OpticianId;
  .... // etc

  db.Entry(booking).State = EntityState.Modified;
  db.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

and your view should have `@model BookingViewModel`

Side note: Your view model should **not** contain property `public Optician Optician { get; set; }` (you binding to the property `public Guid OpticianId { get; set; }`)

Comment: Thank you again Stephen. I thought you had to pass the Id to the POST method. I am starting to understand View Model. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Should also add that `BookingViewModel` should really contain a property `pubic Guid? ID { get; set; }` which you set in the GET method (`ID = booking.ID`) and in the POST method it should be `Booking booking = db.Bookings.Find(model.ID);` Because you have a parameter named `ID` in the method, its automatically bound (for example you don't need a hidden input for the ID property)