# CRUD Edit operation using a ViewModel with unit testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

First of all: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400094/how-to-edit-using-a-viewmodel-in-mvc), but I don't fully understand it, so please don't lock it as a duplicate.

I'm trying to do the Edit operation with a ViewModel.

My problem is for some reason `adds` a new row to the table instead of `editing` it. It all used to work before I went for the testing.

I believe it's something silly I missed but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using `code-first` if it makes any difference

My ViewModel:

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Author")]
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PublicationDate { get; set; }
    public float? Edition { get; set; }
    public SelectList Authors { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller functions:

```
    // GET: Books/Edit/5
    public ViewResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        Book book = db.Books.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);

        var vm = new CreateViewModel()
        {
            AuthorId = book.AuthorId,
            Authors = new SelectList(db.Authors, "Id", "Name"),
            PublicationDate = book.PublicationDate,
            Title = book.Title,
            Edition = book.Edition
        };

        if (book == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        return View(vm);
    }

    // POST: Books/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(CreateViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var repo = new EFLibraryRepository();
            repo.Save(new Book(){
                AuthorId = vm.AuthorId,
                PublicationDate = vm.PublicationDate,
                Title = vm.Title,
                Edition = vm.Edition
            });
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View("Edit", vm);
    }
```

My mock repository:

```
public class EFLibraryRepository : ILibraryRepository
{
    AuthorAndBookDbModel db = new AuthorAndBookDbModel();
    public IQueryable<Author> Authors { get { return db.Authors; } }

    public IQueryable<Book> Books { get { return db.Books; } }

    public void Delete(Book book)
    {
        db.Books.Remove(book);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Delete(Author author)
    {
        db.Authors.Remove(author);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public Book Save(Book book)
    {
        if (book.Id == 0)
        {
            db.Books.Add(book);
        }
        else
        {
            db.Entry(book).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return book;
    }
    public Author Save(Author author)
    {
        if (author.Id == 0)
        {
            db.Authors.Add(author);
        }
        else
        {
            db.Entry(author).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return author;
    }
}
```

The ILibraryRepository:

```
public interface ILibraryRepository
{
    IQueryable<Book> Books { get; }
    IQueryable<Author> Authors { get; }

    Book Save(Book book);
    Author Save(Author author);

    void Delete(Book book);
    void Delete(Author author);
}
```

Comment: Your view model does not have an `Id` property, and when you saving the `Book`, your not setting its `Id` property, so its always `0` which mans you always call `db.Books.Add(book);`

Comment: But you design is wrong anyway. You should be getting the original data model from the database based on the `Id` (just add a `public int? Id { get; set }` property to your view model so its automatically bound), and then you update its properties from the view model.

Comment: Ok works perfectly now. Do you want to add an answer so I can pick it as best?

Comment: Just leave it here and I'll pick it tomorrow. Thank you for the help!

Comment: When you get the info for the edit method in the VM just get the id of the book too and then get that book object from db, edit it, mark it as `EntityState.Modified` and then save it. It will work for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your POST method, you never set the value of the Book's `Id` property so its always `0` (the default value for `int`) so in turn, you always execute the code to add a new `Book`.

You first need to include a property in your view model for the `id` so that its value will be bound in the POST method.

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; } // add this
    ....
```

Note that you do not need to include a hidden input for it in the view assuming your using the default routes (its value will be bound from the route value in the forms `action` attribute).

Then in the POST method, set the `Id` of the `Book` based on the view model

```
repo.Save(new Book() {
    Id = vm.Id, // add
    AuthorId = vm.AuthorId,
    ....
```

However, the correct approach when editing existing records is to get the original data model from the repository based on the `Id` and update its properties, for example

```
Book book = db.Books.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == vm.Id);
book.AuthorId = vm.AuthorId;
....
repo.Save(book);
```

rather than creating a new `Book` instance. Some of the benefits of this approach include

1. Your data models will often include properties that should not be in
   the view (for example, properties to indicate the date a records was
   created, and by who). Creating a new instance of the data model and
   saving it means those properties would be overwritten and set to
   their default values.
2. You can do concurrency checks, for example you can check the
   `TIMESTAMP` values and if they are different, you know that another
   user has modified the record in the meantime (and you might take a
   different course of action rather than just overwriting the previous
   uses changes)